# Python NLTK Chunking

Tags: python-2.7, nltk, chunking

Using NLTK, I would like to write down a tag pattern to handle something like noun phrases with gerunds and/or coordinated noun. After importing essential libraries, I tokenize my candidate text as follows:

`sentences=nltk.word_tokenize('......')`

It contains several sentences. 
Then I tag it by:

`sentences=nltk.pos_tag(sentences)`

I also defined my proposed grammar as:

```
grammar= r"""
Gerunds: {<DT>?<NN>?<VBG><NN>}
Coordinated noun: {<NNP><CC><NNP>|<DT><PRP\$><NNS><CC>
<NNS>|<NN><NNS> <CC><NNS>} """
```

Then, I employ:

```
cp=nltk.RegexpParser(grammar);
for sent in sentences:
   tree = cp.parse(sent)
   for subtree in tree.subtrees():
     if subtree.label()=='Gerunds': print(subtree)
print(cp.parse(sentences));
```

It says `ValueError: chunk structures must contain tagged tokens or trees`

How should I tackle the problem guys?

Comment: Who are the problem guys?

Comment: Seriously, can you post the stack trace?

Comment: You obviously left a step out of your sample code, because `sentences` would have ended up being a list of tagged words, not a list of sentences. In general, `nltk.word_tokenize()` must be used on one sentence at a time.

Answer (score 2):

I did:

`from nltk import word_tokenize, pos_tag`

Then, instead of using `tree = cp.parse(sent)`, and `print(cp.parse(sentences))`, I utilized:

`tree = cp.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentences)))`

and

`print(cp.parse(pos_tag(word_tokenize(sentences))))`

It worked like a charm! :-)

Comment: So, when you looked at the stack trace, you found the solution yourself, am I right?

Comment: See http://www.nltk.org/_modules/nltk/chunk/regexp.html#RegexpChunkParser and http://nbviewer.ipython.org/github/lukewrites/NP_chunking_with_nltk/blob/master/NP_chunking_with_the_NLTK.ipynb